# Website not auto-refresh when using UseHistory in React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using React Router Dom version 5.2.0. The website URL has been successfully changed but the page is not automatically refreshed.

Following is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./home.scss";
import { BlogItem, Button, Gap } from "../../components";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <div className="home-page-wrapper">
      <div className="create-wrapper">
        <Button
          tittle="create blog"
          onClick={() => history.push("/create-blog")}
        />
      </div>
      <Gap height={20} />
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <BlogItem />
        <BlogItem />
        <BlogItem />
        <BlogItem />
      </div>
      <div className="pagination">
        <Button tittle="Previous" />
        <Gap width={20} />
        <Button tittle="Next" />
      </div>
      <Gap height={20} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I hope the website can move pages according to its function, and the website can refresh automatically when the url is changed.

Comment: ***Don't*** remove the `React.StrictMode` component. Bump to `react-router-dom@5.3.3` or higher to use a version that works with React 18 and the `React.StrictMode` component. See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to use useNavigate instead

Comment: Can useNavigate be applied to react router dom version 5.2.0?

Comment: sry, didn't notice. No, you can't. in this case you are right to use history. did you use <Switch> and <BrowserRouter> component for you routes?

Comment: yes you can see my repo in github (https://github.com/hanhafizh/MERN-Site) in src>pages>Home>index.js

Comment: remove strict mode

Comment: can you tell me how?

Comment: remove <React.StrictMode> from you index.js render() function. I don't know why, but it started working fine when i did this

Comment: thank you very much, it works you have helped me to solve this problem

Comment: Please ***don't*** suggest/recommend removing the `React.StrictMode` component, that's just completely the wrong solution to the problem OP has.